# What is the difference between apache2 reload, restart, graceful?

Tags: apache2

I am using apache2 for a project and I am wondering what is exactly the difference between these commands:

```
service apache2 restart
service apache2 reload
service apache2 graceful
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There main difference between the four different ways of stopping/restarting are what does the main process do about its threads, and about itself.

Note that Apache recommends using `apachectl -k` as the command, and for systemd, the command is replaced by `httpd -k`

---

`apachectl -k stop` or `httpd -k stop`

This tells the process to kill all of its threads and then exit

---

`apachectl -k graceful` or `httpd -k graceful`

Apache will advise its threads to exit when idle, and then apache reloads the configuration (it doesn't exit itself), this means statistics are not reset.

---

`apachectl -k restart` or `httpd -k restart`

This is similar to stop, in that the process kills off its threads, but then the process reloads the configuration file, rather than killing itself.

---

`apachectl -k graceful-stop` or `httpd -k graceful-stop`

This acts like `-k graceful` but instead of reloading the configuration, it will stop responding to new requests and only live as long as old threads are around. Combining this with a new instance of `httpd` can be very powerful in having concurrent apaches running while updating configuration files.

---

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html

Recommendation: Use `-k graceful` unless there is something wrong with the main process itself, in which case a combination of `-k stop` and `-k start` or `-k graceful-stop` and `-k start` are the options of choice.

Comment: `service apache2 reload` is equivalent to `-k graceful`. `service apache2 restart` is equivalent to `-k stop` followed by starting the server again. At least in my system; read the init.d script in your distro to make sure.

Comment: @Nicolás I think you meant `service apache2 restart` is equivalent to `-k restart`, isn't it? _(just to be clear)_

Comment: The init.d script in Ubuntu doesn't ever use `-k restart`. `service apache2 restart` is equivalent to `service apache2 stop; service apache2 start`, and `service apache2 stop` runs `apache2 -k stop`. Other distros may vary, look at your own init.d script to be sure.

Comment: If you use systemd, it's not even *possible* for a service unit file to specify a command for restarting; it's a stop followed by start, always, so it can't use -k restart.

Comment: On RedHat/CentOS `systemctl reload httpd.service` is not equivalent to `-k graceful`.  You can't access `-k graceful` via `systemctl` functions, you have to use `httpd -k graceful` (or `/usr/sbin/httpd -k graceful`).  For example, a new vhost conf using a wildcard SSL certificate will not be loaded using `systemctl reload httpd.service`, you have to use `httpd -k graceful`.  I thought I should make this clear to prevent people from restarting apache disrupting connections unnecessarily.

Answer (score 34):

1. Difference between “restart” and “reload”

   - Restart= stop + start
   - Reload = remain running + re-read configuration files.
2. Normal restart and graceful restart, you can reference article:

   https://teckadmin.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/difference-between-graceful-restart-and-normal-restart/

Comment: can you please elaborate here?

Comment: @manetsus elaborate on what specifically?

A graceful is a nicer restart. Restart will stop all worker threads regardless of what they're doing, shutdown, and start up again.
A graceful tells all worker threads to stop once they are finished, and when all the threads terminate, it shuts down the main process and starts up again.

This is important if your apache processes aren't written with the ability to bail out safely. If you are not using a transaction, writing a file, or sending packets, a restart can cause half written/finished data.

It's also very rude to users.

Comment: Ran out of comment space...

By 'rude to users'. If a user has a request processing, even if it can be terminated without causing damage to the system, an apache restart will return a 500 error to the user. Users do not like that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Quick question : Suppose on Amazon ECS , one site with huge number of sub-domains and while adding new sub-domain on fly programmatically , if we set apache2  graceful or reload. That will harm the active request / response on other sub-domains ?

Comment: @Jim Yes, by restarting the server completely it will of course read the configuration files again when it starts back up.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like `graceful` and `reload` are the same for apache2

In `/etc/init.d/apache2`:

```
graceful | reload | force-reload)
# rest of the script
```

Comment: On Red Hat/CentOS `systemctl reload httpd.service` is not equivalent to `-k graceful`.  You can't access `-k graceful` via `systemctl` functions, you have to use `httpd -k graceful` (or `/usr/sbin/httpd -k graceful`).  For example, a new vhost conf using a wildcard SSL certificate will not be loaded using `systemctl reload httpd.service`, you have to use `httpd -k graceful`.  I thought I should make this clear to prevent people from restarting apache disrupting connections unnecessarily.